# Pay With Amazon whitelist not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I've been working to integrate amazon login and pay with a website I've been developing, and it works great, except I want to use the redirect experience rather than the popup so that my application will work on mobile. However, I'm unable to get it to work. I have gone to my application on sellercentral, and added to my allowed Javascript Origins:

```
https://localhost:8443/
https://mysite.co/
https://mysitedev-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/
```

Similarly, under Allowed Return URLS:

```
https://localhost:8443/pay/amazon_pay
https://mysite.co/pay/amazon_pay
https://mysitedev-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/pay/amazon_pay
```

but when I go to click the button from https://localhost:8443/ I get the error:

```
Error Summary
400 Bad Request
The redirect URI you provided has not been whitelisted for your application

Request Details
client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.1fad4ae9338847a094443ce982cd7c96
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fpay%2Famazon_pay%3Fpage%3Dlogin-pay%26extra_amount%3D%26phrase%3Dblack%2520black%2520ocean
response_type=token
scope=profile%20payments%3Awidget
language=
ui_locales=
sandbox=true
```

I'm pretty sure it's an issue with my whitelist, not my code, but if it helps, my code looks like:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%><%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%><script type='text/javascript'>
        function getURLParameter(name, source) {
            return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&|#]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(source)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g,'%20'))||null;
        }
        var accessToken = getURLParameter("access_token", location.hash);
        if (typeof accessToken === 'string' && accessToken.match(/^Atza/)) {
            document.cookie = "amazon_Login_accessToken=" + accessToken + ";secure";
        }

        window.onAmazonLoginReady = function() {
            amazon.Login.setClientId('${client_id}');
            amazon.Login.setUseCookie(true);
        };

        function launchAmazon(){
            console.log("Amazon script loaded.");
            var session = "${session}";
            var access_token = "${access_token}";
            if (session == null || access_token == null) {
                alert("Missing query string parameters from request, verify that access_token & session are present");
            }
            var authRequest;
            OffAmazonPayments.Button("login_widget", "${seller_id}", {
                sellerId: '${seller_id}',
                useAmazonAddressBook: true,
                type:  "PwA",
                size:  "large",
                onSignIn: function(order){
                },
                authorization: function(order){
                    var loginOptions = {scope: 'profile payments:widget',popup: false};
                    authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize(loginOptions, "/pay/amazon_pay?page=login-pay&extra_amount=${extra_amount}&phrase=${phrase}");
                },
                onError: function(error) {
                    alert(error.getErrorCode() + ": " + error.getErrorMessage());
                },
            });
        }
        $.getScript("https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us${sandbox}/js/Widgets.js?sellerId=${seller_id}")
        .done(launchAmazon)
        .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception){
            debugger;
            console.log(exception);
        });
    </script>
    <div id="login_widget_holder" class="amazon_widget_holder">
        <div id="login_widget" class="amazon_widget"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, your redirect URI is not an exact match, because it has a query string  appended, `?page=login-pay&extra_amount=&phrase=black%20black%20ocean`.  Is this supported by the service?  Does it work if you don't include that?  This would seem like a useful test.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Crimony. That fixed it. Thanks for that sanity check, though I'm pretty disappointed in amazon for that one. Now I need to come up with a good way to work around that. Just having that fix though is a load off my mind, I've been scratching my head at this problem off and on for a month now. If you put that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Since your return URL contains dynamic values there is not a work around since that is not allowed due to OAuth constraints. Could you not store these values in a session variable and then read from them when you handle the return?

Comment: @BrentDouglas That's what I'm doing currently to work around it.